# How to find the projection $W$ onto $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Subspace w =
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} such that  $x_1 = x_3$ of R3.

x = \begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}

Question is to find $proj_w (x)$.

Im comfortable finding the projection, but unsure how to get the matrix from the subspace.

Comment: If you have two orthogonal unit vectors $q_1,q_2$ in $W$, then the projector is $Q Q^T$ where $Q=\begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and the projection of $x$ is $Q Q^T x$. Can you make up two such vectors in $W$?

Comment: An exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747024/how-to-find-the-projwx/1747070#1747070 ?

Comment: wow... why are these questions totally identical?

Answer (score 0):

- Consider $W=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x_1=x_3\}$, and set $x=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\a\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-2-a\\1-b\\3-a\end{pmatrix}$ such that
  $\begin{pmatrix}-2-a\\1-b\\3-a\end{pmatrix}\in W^\perp$. Then we solve the following equations.
  \begin{align}
  0&=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}-2-a\\1-b\\3-a\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle=1-2a
  &&\Longrightarrow&a&=\frac{1}{2},\\[3pt]
  0&=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}-2-a\\1-b\\3-a\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle=1-b
  &&\Longrightarrow&b&=1.
  \end{align}
  It follows that ${\rm proj}_W(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\1\\\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$.
- Next, to find the matrix representation of ${\rm proj}_W$, we let $\beta$ be
  the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. By the preceding result, it is not difficult to see that
  $$\gamma=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
  is an ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of ${\rm proj}_W$ corresponding to eigenvalues $1$, $1$, and $0$, respectively. So by taking 
  $Q=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, we conclude that
  \begin{align}
  [{\rm proj}_W]_\gamma&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
  =Q^{-1}[{\rm proj}_W]_\beta Q
  \end{align}
  or
  \begin{align}
  [{\rm proj}_W]_\beta 
  &=Q[{\rm proj}_W]_\gamma Q^{-1}\\
  &=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&1&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&-\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\\
  &=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&1&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}.
  \end{align}